# RequireJS paths config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My development config (in "index.html" file) for RequireJS is:

```
<script src="require-2.1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: 'js',
        paths: {
            angular: 'libraries/angular-1.1.5.min',
            jquery: 'libraries/jquery-2.0.0.min',
            underscore: 'libraries/underscore-1.4.4.min',
            ...
            zeroclipboard: 'plugins/zeroclipboard-1.0.7.min',
            tablesorter: 'plugins/jquery.tablesorter-2.9.1.min',
            ...
        },
        shim: {
            'angular': {
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            'underscore': {
                exports: '_'
            }
        },
        packages: [
            {
                name: 'index',
                location: 'app/index',
                main: 'main'
            }
        ]
    });

    require(['index']);
</script>
```

But on production I have only 2 concatenated files for libraries and plugins:

```
js/libraries.js // all jQuery, AngularJS, RequireJS, Underscore and other libraries concatenated
js/plugins.js // all plugins (already an AMD modules, no need for "shim" config) concatenated
```

So, how do I write my config "paths" now? I don't have any *'libraries/angular-1.1.5.min.js'* and other paths.

My solution is to write:

```
    paths: {
        angular: 'libraries',
        underscore: 'libraries'
    }
```

I associate AngularJS and Underscore to *'libraries.js'* file and everything works perfect. (No need for jQuery and all plugins — they are already an AMD modules).

But is that a right way to write paths? My solution seems to me kinda dirty workaround, not the best practices solution.

My r.js build process:

```
({
baseUrl: 'scripts',
paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery-2.0.0.min',
    ...
    tablesorter: 'jquery.tablesorter-2.0.5.min',
    zeroclipboard: 'zeroclipboard-1.0.7.min'
},
name: 'foo/main',
exclude: [
    'angular',
    'jquery',
    ...
    'tablesorter',
    'zeroclipboard'
],
optimize: 'uglify',
out: 'production/js/foo.js'
})
```

**UPD 1:**

What I want:

```
www.mysite.com/about.html:

<script src="js/libraries.js"></script><-- jQuery (already AMD), AngularJS (not AMD), RequireJS, Underscore (not AMD) and other libraries already here, only 1 http request needed //-->
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script><-- all AMD //-->
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: 'js',
        paths: {
            angular: WHAT I NEED TO WRITE HERE?,
            underscore: WHAT I NEED TO WRITE HERE?
        },
        shim: {
            'angular': {
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            'underscore': {
                exports: '_'
            }
        },
        packages: [
            {
                name: 'about',
                location: 'js',
                main: 'about'
            }
        ]
    });

    require(['about']); // will load "js/about.js"
</script>
```

**UPD 2:**

Ok, it is clear about "priority", so, I don't need for first and second «script» tags (but I need to separate "Require.js" from "libraries.js") — RequireJS will load them automatically. But what should be done with non-AMD libraries in "libraries.js" file?

AngularJS and UnderscoreJS are non-AMD modules, that is why I have to use "shim", right? But to make "shim" work, I need to use "paths" also, so "shim" can locate shimmed modules, right? But I still have only 1 file — "libraries.js" and I cannot write it in "path" option… Just really stuck…

Comment: You should not have to add in those additional script tags, require.js can, and should, load those for you. Is my answer below about the priority option unclear ?

Comment: It is all great with your answer, I just made an update before reading your update :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have common library code preloaded you should use the priority config option.
you could put something like this in your `foo/main.js` file

```
require.config({
    priority: ["libraries", "plugins"]
});
```

And then your build file could look like this.
The libraries and plugins file should contains a define statement that define all dependencies that are considered general / download once.

```
({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-2.0.0.min',
        ...
        tablesorter: 'jquery.tablesorter-2.0.5.min',
        zeroclipboard: 'zeroclipboard-1.0.7.min'
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'foo/main'
            excludes: ...
        },
        {
            name: 'libraries'
        },
        {
            name: 'plugins'
        }
    ],
    optimize: 'uglify',
    out: 'production/js/foo.js'
})
```

Comment: «the idea is that all required bootstrap code is loaded trough 1 file». For example, I have 3 pages on my web site: about, portfolio, contacts. I make 3 different files with my modules (a lot of "define" modules concatenated into 1 file): "about.js", "portfolio.js", "contacts.js". And 4th file is "libraries+plugins.js" — because I want browser to cache this file and never download it again. I cannot afford to put "libraries+plugins.js" code into each of "about.js", "portfolio.js", "contacts.js" files.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense. I think you need to take a look at the `priority` configuration options to allow multi layered output   http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/faq-optimization.html#priority

Comment: @artuska i have edited my question in order to better reflect the priority option in require js

Answer (score 2):

You should use same configuration for both environments. And this configuration that you have should be in the external file. When you optimize it using r.j, all modules already in that single file so RequireJS will just use them without loading. Seems like you need to tune your build process.

Checkout my recent [**blog post**](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs) about it.

Comment: Added my r.js build script. Even after your blogpost I do not understand, how it is possible to keep my config the same for development and production (in "index.html" file).

As you see, I exclude some files from final build to put them in separate file (libraries.js) so browser cache it and do not download it again for other pages on my web site. "libraries.js" contains both AMD modules libraries (like jQuery, it is already an AMD module in its core) and non-AMD libraries (like AngularJS). So, there is no "define" for AngularJS in "libraries.js" file.

Comment: Maybe I should manually make all libraries to be an AMD modules? I mean, just edit Angular.js file and wrap its code in "define('angular', [], function() {...})" function?

Comment: I guess it would make sense those big modules exclude from build. You may want to check https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed project where AngularJS is used together with RequireJS.